# How to count LLVM IR instructions during OpenCL kernel execution?

Tags: compilation, profiling, opencl, llvm, debug-symbols

I am trying to write an OpenCL hostcode for a custom kernel of mine and I want to count the LLVM IR instructions that where executed. My problem is, the LLVM IR representation of the kernel is lost after I build it, and the only thing that exists is the native binary. Is there any way to:

- count the native architecture instructions executed?
- find a mapping between the native architecture instructions and the LLVM IR representation and, through this, manage to count the LLVM IR instructions that were executed?

Comment: Do you want to count the number of LLVM IR instructions generated for an OpenCL Kernel?

Comment: I want to count the number of LLVM IR instructions that get executed for a particular run of an OpencL kernel.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is not directly possible through the OpenCL API. But there are two ways you could achieve counting native/IR instructions using tools:

**IR:**

- You could use the SPIR-V (Khronos-defined IR, similar to LLVM IR, but portable) tools, see this [README](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIR/tree/spirv-1.1#step-6-creating-spir-v-binaries) to generate SPIR-V from an OpenCL source. Then count the IR instructions of the result.

**Native:**

- You can use an offline OpenCL compiler from some SDK, e.g. the Intel OpenCL SDK provides a command line tool called `ioc64` which can generate assembly code from OpenCL and even allows you to specify the target architecture.
- You could try to disassemble the OpenCL-generated binary (via `clGetProgramInfo()` with `CL_PROGRAM_BINARY_SIZES` and `CL_PROGRAM_BINARIES`), e.g. with an appropriate command line tool after storing it to disk.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am interested solely on counting the total number of IR instructions executed. After compiling OpenCL source to SPIR-V, how would I instrument it? Is there something like the LLVM IR C++ API? I can not find anything similar... And let's say I did instrument it, how do I use it from the OpenCL hostcode? `clCreateProgramWithIL` followed by `clBuildProgram` does not seem to work if the SPIR-V binary is not linked with the OpenCL runtime library, which I totally don't get (isn't the linkage supposed to happen by calling `clBuildProgram`? How could it expect for the IR to be already linked?)